# is it possible to download a file using ajax.beginform? or ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

here is the code of my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadItemList(int subcampaignId, string SheetName, string filename)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string url = string.Format("api/report/subcampaign/{0}", subcampaignId);

        var response = await req.GetXMLAsync(url);
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

                xmlDoc.LoadXml(content);

                XmlNodeReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);

                ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);


            }


            IDataTableToWorkbookUtility workbookExportUtility = new DataTableToWorkbookUtility();

            byte[] excelContent = workbookExportUtility
            .ExportDataTableToWorkbook(ds.Tables[0], SheetName)
            .GetBytes();

            return this.File(excelContent, "application/vnd.ms-excel", filename + ".xls");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Debug("CampaignListController/GetAudio: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

when i use ajax.beginform.. instead of downloading the file, response is read as text. i want to use ajax because i want to display a loading bar when the use click the submit button.. all i want to do is to  display a loading status while waiting for the file to be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot upload or download files via AJAX.

you can try below scenerio

If the file is successfully found/created. Send back a JSON result with the link to the file. Then in javascript use windows.location to retrieve the file. When there is an error, the JSON result will contain the error information and this info can be displayed to the user. For this to work, you'll need to create another endpoint (action) that can stream the file.

```
 $.ajax({
    ..
     success: function(data)
     {
      if( data.result=='success' ){
        window.open(download_path + data.fileName); 
        }        
     }
    ..
    })
```

Comment: Hi, where i can get "dowload_path" ? Can you tell me in more detail ? Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can, you need to use the blueimp's file upload jquery [plugin](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). It has a huge set of options and supports cross-domain.

It also has a loading bar that you can implement.